Dual of a pullback of vector spaces
On my studies duals of pullbacks of vector spaces have been showing up, and I'm trying to determine an isomorphism between $(V \times_{Y} W)^{\ast}$ and some construction involving the duals of the three spaces for ease of computations.
Suppose $g_{1}: V \to Y$, $g_{2}: W \to Y$ are the linear maps in the pullback. My first guess was the pushout $V^{\ast} \coprod_{Y^{\ast}} W^{\ast}$, using that  $(-)^{\ast} = Hom(-,\mathbb{R})$ and this functor takes limits to colimits, but it is defined in the dual of the category of vector spaces, so I can't use it.
Next I thought of decomposing a $f \in (V \times_{Y} W)^{\ast}$ into $f_{1} + f_{2}$ with $f_{1} \in V^{\ast}$ and $f_{2} \in W^{\ast}$ by setting $f(v,w) = f(v,0) + f(0,w)$, but this decomposition is not always possible in a pullback of vector spaces since it forces $v$ and $w$ to be in the fibers of $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ at $0$.
I am not really sure how to do this, or even if it's possible. Can someone help me?

Dualisation takes pushouts to pullbacks, not the other way around.

As @ZhenLin notes in the comments, the dualization functor is given by homomorphisms into an object, so it takes pushouts to pullbacks (more generally, colimits to limits), not necessarily the other way round.
However, note that there is a canonical comparison homomorphism $V^{\ast}\sqcup_{Y^{\ast}}W^{\ast}\rightarrow(V\times_YW)^{\ast}$, which is an isomorphism if and only if the pullback is preserved by $(-)^{\ast}$ (the pushout I wrote down is really a pullback in $\mathrm{Vec}_k^{op}$, the codomain of the dualization functor). Now, a nice observation is that $(-)^{\ast}\colon\mathrm{Vec}_k\rightarrow\mathrm{Vec}_k^{op}$ restricts to an equivalence of full subcategories $(-)^{\ast}\colon\mathrm{FinVec}_k\rightarrow\mathrm{FinVec}_k^{op}$. The inclusion $\mathrm{FinVec}_k\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Vec}_k$ automatically preserves and reflects finite colimits and limits (because a finite limit resp. colimit of vector spaces is a subspace resp. quotient of a finite product resp. coproduct and thus finite-dimensional if all the spaces in the diagram are finite-dimensional) and an equivalence of categories always preserves limits and colimits. Thus, if $V$, $Y$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, the comparison homomorphism is an isomorphism.
If you find a symbolic argument easier, the chain of isomorphisms is
$$
(V\times_YW)^{\ast}=(V^{\ast\ast}\times_{Y^{\ast\ast}}W^{\ast\ast})^{\ast}=(V^{\ast}\sqcup_{Y^{\ast}}W^{\ast})^{\ast\ast}=V^{\ast}\sqcup_{Y^{\ast}}W^{\ast},
$$
where we have used that $(-)^{\ast}$ tuns pushouts into pullbacks and double duality.
Lastly, if $Y^{\prime}\le Y$ denotes the subspace of $Y$ generated by the images of $V$ and $W$, then we have $V\times_{Y^{\prime}}W=V\times_YW$ and $Y^{\prime}$ is finite-dimensional if $V$ and $W$ are, so we can actually drop the hypothesis that $Y$ is finite-dimensional and still retain the result.
